# Ruby: variable acting as nul when set to integer

Tags: ruby, variables

After a good 10 minutes of trying to come up with a more informative title, I ran out of ideas.

I have 2 prolems. The first is that whenever I try to input a position for `pos_in`, it registers as `nul` when run through the `case` statement that determines what `m_index` will be for that turn.
The second is that whenever the `AI` takes a turn, it *always* selects `1 1`.

My question is: is there some way to fix this? I've tried switching the input types to no avail and I'm completely clueless on what to do.

My code:

```
$moves = ["x", "o"]
$move = 1
m_index = 0
$spots = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
possiblesx = (1..3)
possiblesy = (1..3)
def board
    puts """
TicTacToe 1.5 by Touka

        #{$spots[0]}|#{$spots[1]}|#{$spots[2]}
        -----
        #{$spots[3]}|#{$spots[4]}|#{$spots[5]}
        -----
        #{$spots[6]}|#{$spots[7]}|#{$spots[8]}
move: #{$c_move}
"""
end
def ai_move
    if $spots[3, 6] == "x" || $spots[4, 8] == "x" || $spots[1, 2] == "x"
        pos_in = "1 1"
    elsif $spots[1, 3] == "x" || $spots[4, 7] == "x"
        pos_in = "1 2"
    elsif $spots[0, 1] == "x" || $spots[6, 4] == "x" || $spots[5, 8] == "x"
        pos_in = "1 3"
    elsif $spots[0, 6] == "x" || $spots[4, 5] == "x"
        pos_in = "2 1"
    elsif $spots[0, 8] == "x" || $spots[1, 7] == "x" || $spots[2, 6] == "x" || $spots[5, 3] == "x"
        pos_in = "2 2"
    elsif $spots[2, 8] == "x" || $spots[3, 4] == "x"
        pos_in = "2 3"
    elsif $spots[0, 3] == "x" || $spots[2, 4] == "x" || $spots[7, 8] == "x"
        pos_in = "3 1"
    elsif $spots[1, 4] == "x" || $spots[6, 8] == "x"
        pos_in = "3 2"
    elsif $spots[6, 7] == "x" || $spots[0, 4] == "x" || $spots[2, 5] == "x"
        pos_in = "3 3"
    else
        aimx = possiblesx.to_a.sample
        aimy = possiblesy.to_a.sample
        pos_in = "#{aimx} #{aimy}"
    end 
end
def game
    system "cls"
    if $move == 1
        $move = 0
    else
        $move = 1
    end
    $c_move = $moves[$move]
    board
    if $opp == 2 && $c_move == "o"
        ai_move
    else
        puts "Enter move coordinates (ex \"1 1\"):"
        pos_in = gets.chomp
    end
    case pos_in
    when ["1 1"]
        m_index = 0
    when ["1 2"]
        m_index = 1
    when ["1 3"]
        m_index = 2
    when ["2 1"]
        m_index = 3
    when ["2 2"]
        m_index = 4
    when ["2 3"]
        m_index = 5
    when ["3 1"]
        m_index = 6
    when ["3 2"]
        m_index = 7
    when ["3 3"]
        m_index = 8
    end
    if $spots[m_index] == " "
        $spots[m_index] = "#{$c_move}"
    else
        if $opp == 2 && $c_move == "o"
            $move = $c_move
            game
        end
        system "cls"
        puts "

        Error.
    Re-enter $move."
        sleep(3)
        system "cls"
        $move = c_$move
        game
    end
    system "cls"
    game
end
puts "Play vs. [1]Friend or [2]AI"
$opp = gets.to_i
game
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had was with your scoping, along with the fact you were trying to match a string to an array as Piotr Kruczek pointed out.

Make the `pos_in` variable global and change the when statements from an array input to a string.

Here is the working version of your code:

```
$moves = ["x", "o"]
$move = 1
m_index = 0
$spots = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
$pos_in = nil

def board
    puts """
TicTacToe 1.5 by Touka

        #{$spots[0]}|#{$spots[1]}|#{$spots[2]}
        -----
        #{$spots[3]}|#{$spots[4]}|#{$spots[5]}
        -----
        #{$spots[6]}|#{$spots[7]}|#{$spots[8]}
move: #{$c_move}
"""
end
def ai_move
    if $spots[3, 6] == "x" || $spots[4, 8] == "x" || $spots[1, 2] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 1"
    elsif $spots[1, 3] == "x" || $spots[4, 7] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 2"
    elsif $spots[0, 1] == "x" || $spots[6, 4] == "x" || $spots[5, 8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 3"
    elsif $spots[0, 6] == "x" || $spots[4, 5] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 1"
    elsif $spots[0, 8] == "x" || $spots[1, 7] == "x" || $spots[2, 6] == "x" || $spots[5, 3] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 2"
    elsif $spots[2, 8] == "x" || $spots[3, 4] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 3"
    elsif $spots[0, 3] == "x" || $spots[2, 4] == "x" || $spots[7, 8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 1"
    elsif $spots[1, 4] == "x" || $spots[6, 8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 2"
    elsif $spots[6, 7] == "x" || $spots[0, 4] == "x" || $spots[2, 5] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 3"
    else
        aimx = (1..3).to_a.sample
        aimy = (1..3).to_a.sample
        $pos_in = "#{aimx} #{aimy}"
    end 
end
def game
  m_index = nil
    system "cls"
    if $move == 1
        $move = 0
    else
        $move = 1
    end
    $c_move = $moves[$move]
    board
    if $opp == 2 && $c_move == "o"
        ai_move
    else
        puts "Enter move coordinates (ex \"1 1\"):"
        $pos_in = gets.chomp
    end
    case $pos_in
    when "1 1"
        p m_index = 0
    when "1 2"
        p m_index = 1
    when "1 3"
        p m_index = 2
    when "2 1"
        p m_index = 3
    when "2 2"
        p m_index = 4
    when "2 3"
        p m_index = 5
    when "3 1"
        p m_index = 6
    when "3 2"
        p m_index = 7
    when "3 3"
        p m_index = 8
    end
    if $spots[m_index] == " "
        $spots[m_index] = "#{$c_move}"
    else
        if $opp == 2 && $c_move == "o"
            $move = $c_move
            game
        end
        system "cls"
        puts "

        Error.
    Re-enter $move."
        sleep(3)
        system "cls"
        $move = c_$move
        game
    end
    system "cls"
    game
end
puts "Play vs. [1]Friend or [2]AI"
$opp = gets.to_i
game
```

Comment: After scouring my code for a while, I got it to work. This issue was just me being tired and clueless. (and oddly enough, the `ai_move` method doesn't work with that structure. Well, not as it should.)

Answer (score 1):

You assign

```
pos_in = "1 1"
```

as a String, while in you case statement you check for Array

```
case pos_in
when ["1 1"]
```

Comment: I caught this after looking my code over for the millionth time. This whole issue was me being a sleepy idiot. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As Stated by Piotr and Menelik, there were a few obvious errors in this. Oddly enough, the structure of `ai_move` was one of those. The working code is as follows. It's not the cleanest thing ever and there are some bugs to iron out but it does it's job.

```
$moves = ["x", "o"]
$move = 1
m_index = 0
$spots = Array.new(9, " ")
$possiblesx = [1, 2, 3]
$possiblesy = [1, 2, 3]
def board
    puts """
TicTacToe 1.5 by Touka

        #{$spots[0]}|#{$spots[1]}|#{$spots[2]}
        -----
        #{$spots[3]}|#{$spots[4]}|#{$spots[5]}
        -----
        #{$spots[6]}|#{$spots[7]}|#{$spots[8]}
move: #{$c_move}
"""
end
def ai_move
    if $spots[3] == "x" && $spots[6] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 1"
    elsif $spots[4] == "x" && $spots[8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 1"
    elsif $spots[1] == "x" && $spots[2] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 1"
    elsif $spots[1] == "x" && $spots[3] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 2"
    elsif $spots[4] == "x" && $spots[7] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 2"
    elsif $spots[0] == "x" && $spots[1] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 3"
    elsif $spots[6] == "x" && $spots[4] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 3"
    elsif $spots[5] == "x" && $spots[8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "1 3"
    elsif $spots[0] == "x" && $spots[6] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 1"
    elsif $spots[4] == "x" && $spots[5] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 1"
    elsif $spots[0] == "x" && $spots[8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 2"
    elsif $spots[1] == "x" && $spots[7] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 2"
    elsif $spots[2] == "x" && $spots[6] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 2"
    elsif $spots[5] == "x" && $spots[3] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 2"
    elsif $spots[2] == "x" && $spots[8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 3"
    elsif $spots[3] == "x" && $spots[4] == "x"
        $pos_in = "2 3"
    elsif $spots[0] == "x" && $spots[3] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 1"
    elsif $spots[2] == "x" && $spots[4] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 1"
    elsif $spots[7] == "x" && $spots[8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 1"
    elsif $spots[1] == "x" && $spots[4] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 2"
    elsif $spots[6] == "x" && $spots[8] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 2"
    elsif $spots[6] == "x" && $spots[7] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 3"
    elsif $spots[0] == "x" && $spots[4] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 3"
    elsif $spots[2] == "x" && $spots[5] == "x"
        $pos_in = "3 3"
    else
        aimx = $possiblesx.sample
        aimy = $possiblesy.sample
        $pos_in = "#{aimx} #{aimy}"
    end 
end
def game
    system "cls"
    if $move == 1
        $move = 0
    else
        $move = 1
    end
    $c_move = $moves[$move]
    board
    if $opp == 2 && $c_move == "o"
        ai_move
    else
        puts "Enter move coordinates (ex \"1 1\"):"
        $pos_in = gets.chomp
    end
    case $pos_in
    when "1 1"
        m_index = 0
    when "1 2"
        m_index = 1
    when "1 3"
        m_index = 2
    when "2 1"
        m_index = 3
    when "2 2"
        m_index = 4
    when "2 3"
        m_index = 5
    when "3 1"
        m_index = 6
    when "3 2"
        m_index = 7
    when "3 3"
        m_index = 8
    end
    if $spots[m_index] == " "
        $spots[m_index] = "#{$c_move}"
    else
        if $opp == 2 && $c_move == "o"
            $move = $c_move
            game
        end
        system "cls"
        puts "

        Error.
    Re-enter move."
        sleep(3)
        system "cls"
        $move = $c_move
        game
    end
    system "cls"
    game
end
puts "Play vs. [1]Friend [2]AI"
$opp = gets.to_i
game
```